# Given the $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n + 1} (x + 1)^{n + 2}}{(n + 2)!}$ for all real numbers $x$. Describe the behavior of the curve.

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

> Given the $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n + 1} (x + 1)^{n + 2}}{(n + 2)!}$ for all real numbers $x$. Describe the behavior of the curve.

The answer provided is this.
$$f'(-1)=0,$$ $$\frac{f''(-1)}{2!} = \frac{1}{3!}$$ $\Rightarrow$ $$f''(-1)=\frac{2!}{3!}>0$$ $\Rightarrow$ concave up.
Could anyone please provide more details. Really stuck on this one.

Comment: Let $g(x)=f(x-1)$ and see if it looks familiar.

Comment: Could you provide more context? What information have past problems that asked you to describe the behavior of the curve asked you to provide? And what part of the solution stumps you?

Comment: @NinadMunshi The question is to describe the behavior of the curve. The options are 1. Relative minimum at x= -1. 2. Relative Maximum at x= -1. 3. Inflection Point at x = -1. I do not understand why the second derivative is being set equal to 1/3!, and where that even came from actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a hint:$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n + 1} (x + 1)^{n + 2}}{(n + 2)!}
\\f(x)=\frac{(-1)^1(x+1)^2}{2!}+\frac{(-1)^2(x+1)^3}{3!}+\frac{(-1)^3(x+1)^4}{4!}+\frac{(-1)^4(x+1)^5}{5!}+\cdots\\f(x)=-\frac{(x+1)^2}{2!}+\frac{(x+1)^3}{3!}-\frac{(x+1)^4}{4!}+\frac{(x+1)^5}{5!}+\cdots$$now take $f',f''$ at $x=-1$
$$f'(x)=-\frac{2(x+1)^1}{2!}+\frac{3(x+1)^2}{3!}-\frac{4(x+1)^3}{4!}+\frac{5(x+1)^4}{5!}+\cdots\\f'(-1)=0\\f''(x)=-\frac{2}{2!}+\frac{6(x+1)^1}{3!}-\cdots\\f''(-1)=-1$$                            [image]

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{aligned}f(x)&=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-(x+1))^{n+2}}{(n+2)!}\end{aligned}
 = -\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-(x+1))^n}{n!}+1-(x+1)\\=-x-e^{-x-1}
$$

I'm not exactly sure because the value given for f'' doesn't fit and function is concave down unless I made a mistake somewhere